# Logged out sessions get restored by back button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am making a login page . When i log out i clear the cookies. but when i press the back button after logging out the session gets restored. How can i avoid the session restore..

Comment: What makes you think that the session gets restored?

Comment: Are you sure you're deleting whatever session cookie your framework is using to track sessions (as opposed to cookies you have set)?

Answer (score 8):

This is probably a misunderstanding.

When pressing the <kbd>back</kbd> button, you are most likely seeing a cached version of the page in the browser. This does **not** mean that you are still logged in.

Try refreshing the previous page. It should show the login dialog.

If you want to prevent the page from being shown in this way, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006467/safari-back-button-not-honouring-php-logout-session) is an approach for turning off the browser's caching.

If you actually remain logged in, then something is wrong. In that case, we need to see some code.

Comment: even after clearing the cache it gets restored after the browser prompts for resending the information..

Comment: @user ah, but that is a different case: Then your login credentials actually get re-sent. You might be able to work around that by doing a header redirect to the target page when you log the user in (instead of showing the contents straight away).

Comment: yes he should use redirect-after-post pattern to deal with this

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy fix for your problem is provided by the [session_destroy php man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Comment: Is it possible to delete the logged in data via cookies without creating sessions in php..

Answer (score 2):

From the comments it appears your issue is that when you click Back on your browser, the browser prompts you to re-send POST data. Of course when you do this, you just re-send the login data, thus immediately logging the user back in. The solution to avoiding the annoying browser prompt to resend POST data, and thus also avoid logging the user back in, is to use the "redirect-after-post" pattern.

Have the POST target of your login form be some other page - **not** your login welcome page or whatever. This target page processes the login info, does authorisation, **and then does a redirect** to either the welcome page (on success) or back to the login page if failed to authenticate.

This way you will avoid the browser prompt and the user being logged back in. Really *all* forms should implement this pattern, as it results in a better user experience and avoids pitfalls like the one you have experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code :
  Logged out sessions get restored by back button issues has been resolved.

**Link:**

```
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
 header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Comment: The codingsolver.com link looks dead, and has some spam stuff now.