# PHP Sessions: Issue with back button

Tags: php, session, logout

I am having trouble with my session script. I include this file call functions.php in every file I need a session in.

```
<?php

session_start(); {

  if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }

  }

?>
```

And then I use this file to logout. Called logout.php

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
session_destroy();
// We redirect them to the login page
header("Location: homepage.php");
die("Redirecting to: homepage.php");
?>
```

Can anyone help me fix it so that when a user clicks the logout link they cannot go back to the members area and be logged in again.

Comment: You must give more information. Where is `loggedin()` called?. Where does `user_id` gets set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I assume the problem was this,
You just destroy the session within the logout.php, but not clearing the session variables. Please take a look at the [documentation](http://us.php.net/session_destroy),

What happened in your case is, whenever you going back to the home page, you restart the session, therefore you will be able to access the `$_SESSION['username']` since you did not clear the variable and you get logged in.

Solution for your problem is

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
session_unset(); // need to be called before session_destroy()
session_destroy();
// We redirect them to the login page
header("Location: homepage.php");
die("Redirecting to: homepage.php");
?>
```

or you can simply clear the `$_SESSION['username']` within logout.php script, and you don't necessarily need to destroy the session at all.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It could well be the browsers cache displaying the page, if you logout, clear the cache and then press back does it still do the same?

I found a previous question which may help you:
[Stopping the back button from exposing secure pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964407/stopping-the-back-button-from-exposing-secure-pages)